# The PATCH method is not supported for route roles. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-permission

I want to make role n permission using spatie laravel. I can't edit my role because of the error :

> The PATCH method is not supported for route roles. Supported methods:
> GET, HEAD, POST.

**Controller:**

```
public function edit(string $id)
{
    $role = Role::find($id);
    $permission = Permission::get();
    $rolePermissions = DB::table("role_has_permissions")->where("role_has_permissions.role_id",$id)
        ->pluck('role_has_permissions.permission_id','role_has_permissions.permission_id')
        ->all();

    return view('roles.edit',compact('role','permission','rolePermissions'));
}

public function update(Request $request, string $id)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'permission' => 'required',
    ]);

    $role = Role::find($id);
    $role->name = $request->input('name');
    $role->save();

    $role->syncPermissions($request->input('permission'));

    return redirect()->route('roles.index')
        ->with('success','Role updated successfully');
}
```

**Blade:**

```
<form action='{{ url('roles/') }}' method='post'>
                        @csrf
                        @method('PUT')
                        <div class="my-3 p-3 bg-body rounded shadow-sm">
                            <a href='{{ url('roles') }}' class="btn btn-secondary">Back</a>

                            {!! Form::model($role, ['method' => 'PATCH','route' => ['roles.update', $role->id]]) !!}
                            
                            <div class="mb-3 row">
                                <label for="permission" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Permission</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    {{-- <input type="text" class="form-control" name='permission' value="{{ $role->permission }}" id="permission"> --}}
                                    {!! Form::text('name', null, array('placeholder' => 'Name','class' => 'form-control')) !!}
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

**Route:**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
    Route::resource('admin', adminController::class);
    Route::resource('produk', produkController::class);
    Route::resource('roles', roleController::class);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form action is not correctly pointing to a specific route for updating a role. It should be like this:

```
<form action='{{ route('roles.update', $role->id) }}' method='post'>
```

Add the `@method('PATCH')` directive to your HTML form in the edit view.

```
<form action='{{ route('roles.update', $role->id) }}' method='post'>
    @csrf
    @method('PATCH')
    <div class="my-3 p-3 bg-body rounded shadow-sm">
        <a href='{{ url('roles') }}' class="btn btn-secondary">Back</a>

        <div class="mb-3 row">
            <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Role Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ $role->name }}" id="name">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Add your permission selection input here -->

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update Role</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Finally, make sure you clear your routes.

```
php artisan route:clear
```

Comment: i already add this method put but still cant